# Tensorflow: how to reuse your LSTM Cell after the session is closed?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, lstm

I have the following code for prediction using `BasicLSTMCell`.

```
def predict(self, x, W, b):
    x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, n_input])
    x = tf.split(x,n_input,1)
    rnn_cell = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden)
    outputs, states = rnn.static_rnn(rnn_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)
    return tf.matmul(outputs[-1], W) + b
```

My training phase give me `W_opt` and `b_opt` (in addition to the parameters hidden in the `BasicLSTMCell` which I want to use for predicting on the new data.

However, the testing part is in separate function, and the `session` from the training phase is already closed.

If I try to use

```
y_tf = self.predict(np.array(cur_X), self.W_opt, self.b_opt)
y = session.run(y_tf)
```

which uses the `predict` method described above, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Variable rnn/basic_lstm_cell/kernel already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True or reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope?
```

So how to better fix this error for this particular situation? I have seen some other QA about the possibility of reusing `BasicLSTMCell`. Would it be appropriate in this particular situation, or it is better to share `session` between the methods without closing it, or there is some better way?

(I am new to tf, so, while I think I can make it work somehow, I want to see what is the most proper way to do it. Thanks.)

**UPDATE**:
I have tried to use the same code for prediction under the same `with 
tf.Session() as session` that I use for the training phase, but I get the same mistake.
If I set `reuse=True` flag I get the following error instead:

```
ValueError: Variable rnn/basic_lstm_cell/kernel does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope?
```

If I set `reuse=tf.get_variable()` flag, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Trying to share variable rnn/basic_lstm_cell/kernel, but specified dtype float64 and found dtype float32_ref.
```

I have no idea what this error means, and why I cannot reuse my `BasicLSTMCell` in the same session.

Comment: What do you mean by ' the `session` from the training phase is already closed' 
do you mean something like this?
`with tf.Session():
    training_code`
and then 
`with tf.Session():
    testing_code`

Comment: After closing the session, all variables' state is lost. You have to save it, then restore back in a new session.

Comment: I tried to reuse it again under the same `with tf.Session() as session`, but I still get the same error. If I set `reuse=True` I still get the error, just another one.

Comment: Provide MCVE as in https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. In your case, it might be the whole training script